Validate all my model elements has same value in java
I have Model Class
public class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private String location;
    //getters and setters
}

List<MyObject> models = new ArrayList<>();

How can I validate that location in all objects of models are of same location? Like return true only when location of all models are same else false using java streams?
I can do using traditional for loop.

something like models.stream().map(MyObject::getLocation).distinct().count() == 1 ?! (or ... <= 1 to accept an empty list) - but not the best solution for bigger lists

... adding .limit(2) before .count() will avoid too many iterations (for bigger invalid lists)

You will need to extract the location from one object to compare with all the others:
String expected = models.get(0).getLocation();

Then you can stream the models and use allMatch to test them:
models.stream().allMatch(m -> m.getLocation().equals(expected));

In the latest versions of Java, you can use getFirst() instead of get(0). And you can combine these pieces into a one-liner as follows:
models.stream().allMatch(m -> m.getLocation().equals(models.getFirst().getLocation());

If you pull out the location from the first item separately, you need to be careful that the list is not empty, or you'll get an exception. However, in the one-line version, the lambda will never be called if the list is empty, so it is not a concern.

I like your answer better than mine! +1
